# restrict type to string subtype

Tags: typescript, types

I want some literal type restriction like this:

```js
type StringA = string
type StringB = string

const foo = (a: StringA, b: StringB) => {  }

foo("123" as StringB, "abc" as StringA) // should fail
foo("123" as StringA, "abc" as StringB)
```

But without type alias, actually making its own type. I know I can make an object as a workaround but I'd like to know if I can keep using strings since it makes everything much cleaner in my case

Comment: What's the difference between `StringA` and `StringB`? And what's their purpose? why don't you just use `string`?

Comment: The strings are dot notation object paths or indexes. I simply want to ensure many different internal functions are called with the right parameter types without cluttering all with generics

Comment: you could use a technique called Branded primitives to create "subtypes" so that you simply keep the two types apart or you could type `StringA` and `StringB` to the actual paths: https://tsplay.dev/m07zDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the branded types

(more code on https://tsplay.dev/dimava-brand-v1)

```
declare const Brand: unique symbol;
type Branded<T, B> = T & { [Brand]: B };
type StringA = Branded<string, 'StringA'>;
type StringB = Branded<string, 'StringB'>;
const foo = (a: StringA, b: StringB) => {  }
foo("123" as StringB, "abc" as StringA) // should fail
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Argument of type 'StringB' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StringA'.
foo("123" as StringA, "abc" as StringB)
```

You may use e.g. `import {Opaque} from 'type-fest'` or some other libraries I forgot